# Remove duplicates with pandas while preserving the order [python]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have a column in my df from which, I need to remove case sensitive duplicates keeping the first occurrence. The problem is that I may have on certain rows, words separated by ',' or containing '-' between them. Is there a way to clean this data preserving the order in the same time?

```
this is how my data looks like

3sprouts Cesto de Roupa Cisne Sprouts, 3Sprouts, Organizador
Bright-Starts Mordedor Chocalho Rattle & Teethe, bright Starts, Rosa/Roxo
Bright-Starts Mordedor Twist & Teethe, Starts, Multicor

#this is how it should look like

 3sprouts Cesto de Roupa Cisne, Organizador
Bright-Starts Mordedor Chocalho Rattle & Teethe, Rosa/Roxo
Bright-Starts Mordedor Twist & Teethe, Multicor
```

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why 'bright Starts' in second row has to be removed?(case sensitive?) and ', Rosa/Roxo' becomes ',Rosa/Roxo'? (space)

Comment: @SCKU 'bright Starts'  has to be removed since there's 'Bright-Starts' at the beginning of the sentence. As for the space before the comma and Rosa/Roxo, that does not matter(I'll modify in the description also, thank you)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I think it sould called "case insensitive" or ? ( if 'bright Starts' matches 'Bright-Starts', the first B is case insensitive?)

Comment: @SCKU yes actually, if is the same word should be eliminated no matter if is written in lower, upper, proper case

Comment: hi! Is any one of the answers below working? If so & if you wish, you might consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) one of them to signal others that the issue is resolved. If not, you can provide feedback so they can be improved (or removed altogether)

Answer (score 1):

Assumption:

- the word containgin `-` will not be removed.

Some ideas:

- case sensitive duplicates: should be case **in**sensitive IMO, so compare with `.lower()`.
- keeping the first occurrence: delete the others.
- words separated by ',' or containing '-' between them: split word if `-` exists, then strip `,` for comparasion

```
import re
import itertools

sentences = [
    '3sprouts Cesto de Roupa Cisne Sprouts, 3Sprouts, Organizador',
    'Bright-Starts Mordedor Chocalho Rattle & Teethe, bright Starts, Rosa/Roxo',
    'Bright-Starts Mordedor Twist & Teethe, Starts, Multicor'
]

for s in sentences: 
    s_split = s.split(' ') #keep original sentence split by ' '
    s_split_without_comma = [i.strip(',') for i in s_split]
    #get compare word split by '-' and ' ', use re or itertools
    #method 1: re
    compare_words = re.split(' |-', s)
    #method 2: itertools
    compare_words = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([i.split('-') for i in s_split]))
    #method 3: DIY
    compare_words = []
    for i in s_split:
        compare_words += i.split('-')

    # strip ','
    compare_words_without_comma = [i.strip(',') for i in compare_words]
    
    # start to compare
    need_removed_index = []
    for word in compare_words_without_comma:
        matched_indexes = []
        for idx, w in enumerate(s_split_without_comma):
            if word.lower() in w.lower().split('-'):
                matched_indexes.append(idx)
        if len(matched_indexes) >1: #has_duplicates
            need_removed_index += matched_indexes[1:]
    need_removed_index = list(set(need_removed_index))
    
    # keep remain and join with ' '
    print(" ".join([i for idx, i in enumerate(s_split) if idx not in need_removed_index]))
```

sould print:

```
3sprouts Cesto de Roupa Cisne Sprouts, Organizador
Bright-Starts Mordedor Chocalho Rattle & Teethe, Rosa/Roxo
Bright-Starts Mordedor Twist & Teethe, Multicor
```

It has a little different compared to answer, but I still can't figure out why `Sprouts` also removed in row 1 ('3sprouts' matches 'sprouts'??)

Never mind... just give some concepts.

FYI.

Answer (score 0):

```
#sample dataframe used by me for testing:
df=pd.DataFrame({'col': {0: '3sprouts Cesto de Roupa Cisne Sprouts, 3Sprouts, Organizador',
  1: 'Bright-Starts Mordedor Chocalho Rattle & Teethe, bright Starts, Rosa/Roxo',
  2: 'Bright-Starts Mordedor Twist & Teethe, Starts, Multicor'}})
```

Try:

```
out=df['col'].str.title().str.split(', ',expand=True)
#For checking purpose
real=df['col'].str.split(', ',expand=True)
#for assigning purpose
real[1]=real[1].mask(out[0].str.contains(f'({"|".join(out[1])})'))
#checking if value in col 0 of out is present in the col 1 of out and passing that mask to real 
real[2]=real[2].mask(out[0].str.contains(f'({"|".join(out[2])})'))
#checking if value in col 0 of out is present in the col 2 of out and passing that mask to real 
df['col']=real.apply(lambda x:', '.join(x.dropna()),1)
#finally joining values by ', '
```

Output of `df`:

```
    col
0   3sprouts Cesto de Roupa Cisne Sprouts, Organizador
1   Bright-Starts Mordedor Chocalho Rattle & Teethe, Rosa/Roxo
2   Bright-Starts Mordedor Twist & Teethe, Multicor
```